# Get the closest className

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the closest anchor className that's clicked, however, not every link will contain a class therefore the parent class would be the runner up. the className will be different in many cases so hard coding class names is not expected.

i'm simply trying to identify the location of a duplicate link by the class name to see which one performs better.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if ($("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").length > 1) {
        thisAttr = $(this).closest().attr('class');
        alert('\nClass = ' + thisAttr + ' \n\nYes, this is duplicate link\n\n');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('\nNo, this is NOT a duplicate link\n\n');
        return false;
    }
});


<div id="navigation">
    <div class="utility">
        <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> (Google is not a dup)</div>
        <BR>
        <div class="test"><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> (Example is a duplicate)</div>
        <BR>
        <div><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a> (Amazon is a dup)</div>
        <BR>
        <div><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a> (Amazon is a dup)</div>
        <BR>
        <div class="hello"><a href="http://www.intranet.com">Intranet</a> (Intranet is not dup)</div>
        <BR>
        <div class="world"><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> (Example is a dup)</div>
        <BR>
        <div><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> (Example is a dup)</div>
        <BR>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/no4gkk0n/12/

Comment: What does the DOM element's class name have to do with whether it is a duplicate link or not?  In your example the duplicate Amazon links you show do not even have class names.

Comment: _"to see which one performs better."_ ? What is criteria for _"performs better"_ ? What is expected result ?

Comment: For google link it would be "utility" then for the 1st Example link it would be "test" and then Amazon would be "utility". That's the idea anyway.

Comment: `thisAttr = $(this).closest('[class]').attr('class');` like this??? But i'm completly lost trying understand any logic there

Comment: Edit: Yes, that solves it. I just needed '[class]' Wolff. http://jsfiddle.net/no4gkk0n/13/ When a duplicate link existed, I just needed a way to identify it by something/anything that's unique so I thought a class would do it. I'll use this class name to send it to my analytical package so I can track which duplicate link is performing better on a page.

Comment: I just don't understand the DOM traversal here.  Your first conditional (checking on `a[href='*']`) determines if there are duplicates (i.e. more than one element that meets that criteria).  What do DOM traversal and class names have to do with this?  Are you trying to apply a specific class to, for example highlight where the duplicates are?

Comment: Wolff can you add this as the answer so I may provide credit?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to specify the element you need to find. Closest Return the first ancestor of selected element.

```
thisAttr = $(this).closest().attr('class');
```

in your case you are calling closest without any selector. This means you are not specifying which closest element you are trying to catch. You should pass a selector or element along with closest function.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give the closes div classes name which are same to the current anchor :

```
 $("a").click(function () {
                    if ($("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").length > 1) {
                        var $parentDiv = $(this).parent();
                        var value = $(this).attr("href");
                        var $element = $parentDiv.siblings('[class]');
                        if ($element !== null || $element !== undefined)
                        {
                            var alertClasses;
                            for (var i = 0; i < $element.length; i++) {
                                var $tempele = $element.eq(i);
                                if ($tempele.children('a').prop('href') == value)
                                {
                                    alertClasses = $tempele.prop('class');

                                }
                                else if ($tempele.children('a').prop('href') == value + '/') {
                                        alertClasses = $tempele.prop('class');

                                    }

                            }
                            alert('\nClass = ' + alertClasses + ' \n\nYes, this is duplicate link\n\n');
                        }
                     return false;
                    } else {
                        alert('\nNo, this is NOT a duplicate link\n\n');
                        return false;
                    }
```